# Plotting the logit of Occurence Against Year in R

Tags: r

I have the following occurrence data

[image]

I am trying to sum the number of 1's for each year to get the number of 1's for each year. I then want to repeat this for the number of 0's each year and calculate the proportion of 1's for each year, log-transform this and plot the transformed proportion against year.

I have tried using a for loop for summing the number of 1's (which I called present)

```
    present = matrix(numeric(length = length(Rabbit_10$Occurrence)))
for (i in 1:nrow(Rabbit_10$Year)) {
  if (Rabbit_10[Rabbit_10$Occurrence == 1]){
    present = sum(Rabbit_10[Rabbit_10$Occurrence == 1])
  }
}
present
```

but I got the error message:

> Error in 1:nrow(Rabbit_10$Year) : argument of length 0.

I have tried to Google possible solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: Hi, I haven't included all the additional columns but see this:

`# creating dataset with binary presence,absence
df1 = data.frame(occurence = sample(0:1,100, replace = TRUE),
                 year = sample(1770:1780,100, replace = TRUE))

new_data = df1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% # grouping by year
  count(occurence) %>% # counting each the number each category appeared
  mutate(prop = log(n/(n+lead(n)))) %>% # creating proportion
  filter(occurence == 0) # filtering out rows that aren't needed


ggplot(data = new_data) + geom_point(aes(x = year, y = prop)) # plotting`

Comment: The above should work to calculate proportion if both 0 and 1 are present for each year, if not you'll need to put some additional checks in. Also, you'll need... library(tidyverse)

Comment: Thank you for this! Would it be okay to ask how to do these additional checks as there are not 1's and 0's for each year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## creating dataset with binary presence,absence

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  occurence = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  year = sample(1770:1780, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

## splitting data

```
df1_list <- df1 %>%
  group_by(year, occurence) %>% # grouping by occurence and year
  summarise(freq_group = n()) %>% # creating a frequency for 0 and 1 for each year
  ungroup() %>% # ungrouping
  group_split(year) # splitting dataset by year into a list
```

## lapplying to each dataframe for all years

```
df1_list <- lapply(df1_list, function(x) {
  x %>%
    add_count() %>% # adding count of how many rows exist per group
    mutate(prop = case_when(
      n == 2 & occurence == 1 ~ log(freq_group / sum(freq_group)), # in cases where n is 2 (indicating two rows) and occurence is 1
      n == 1 & occurence == 1 ~ log(freq_group / sum(freq_group)), # in cases where n is 1 and occurence is 1
      n == 1 & occurence == 0 ~ log(0) # in cases where n is 1 and occurence is 0 it returns log(0) -inf
    ))})
```

## plotting

```
plot1 <- bind_rows(df1_list) %>% # binding data
  filter(!is.na(prop)) %>% # filtering out rows where prop is NA
  ggplot(data = .) + # plotting
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = prop))
```

Comment: Not sure if this covers everything, I would see how it works with your dataset and report back at some point. As mentioned, you'll need tidyverse.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think it works in general but I got this message "`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument." I am not sure how to deal with this as I don't really use tidyverse

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it works great I was stupid and didn't type in plot1 after the code to get the plot. Thank you for your help, you've been amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Using the same data as @Dasr, you can also do this all in one go with `ggplot`

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  occurence = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  year = sample(1770:1780, 100, replace = TRUE))


ggplot(df1, aes(x=year, y=occurence)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group=year), 
               geom="point", 
               fun=function(x)log(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful too